# What's the effect of ui-g-nopad?

Tags: css, primefaces

I would like to know what's the effect of "ui-g-nopad".
I see it a lot in the code of an application and I can't understand what it does exactly, cause the result is always the same if I put it or not.

```
<div class="ui-g ui-g-nopad">
...
</div>
```

I read doc (https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/grid.xhtml) but it's not really explicit neither...

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the `primeng.css` file:

```
.ui-g-nopad {
    padding: 0;
}
```

This means it uses CSS to set padding to zero.